# Select only the X value of nodes data with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get only the x-values of the nodes data (node.data()). At the moment I get the whole Object {x: 1, y: 0.4}. I want to compare the previous elements value with the actual. Maybe there is also a way to access the previous value with d.x instead of accessing the x-value using node.data()[i-1]?

```
node.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .text(function(d,i) {

        console.log(node.data()[i])

        var header = d3.select(this);
        if(d.y < 0.7){
            header.style("fill", "green");
        }
        return prozent(d.y); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `d.x` would be the current x value and `node.data()[i-1].x` would be the previous x value, where i > 0.

The alternative is you could just use a var like so:

```
var lastx = undefined;

node.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
.text(function(d,i) {

    console.log(d.x, lastx); // do whatever you want to do comparing d.x and lastx

    var header = d3.select(this);
    if(d.y < 0.7){
        header.style("fill", "green");
    }
    lastx = d.x; // make this the previous value for the next element
    return prozent(d.y); });
```